# Inverse Gamma function for integers (Hankel)

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, gamma-function

So I want to prove that *for all integers* $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ it holds that $$F(n):= \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int\limits_{\gamma}^{} s^{-n}e^{s} ds = \frac{1}{\Gamma(n)},$$ with $\gamma$ the 'Hankel'-contour:

[image: http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/images/0/02/Gamma-function-4.png.]

I've already proven the more general case, i.e. that $$F(z)= \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int\limits_{\gamma}^{} s^{-z}e^{s} ds = \frac{1}{\Gamma(z)},$$
for all $z \in \mathbb{C},$ but I also want to prove this special case separately.

Just to be complete: the gamma function is defined as $\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} t^{z-1}e^{-t}dt$ and has the property that for all $n=1,2,\ldots$ it holds that that $\Gamma(n) = (n-1)!$.

Any help would be dearly appreciated.

**EDIT:** I now have successfully proven that $$F(z-1)=(z-1) \cdot F(z),$$ and for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ I've proven the property. But now I am stuck on the question for all negative numbers.

Comment: If $n \leqslant 0$, then $s \mapsto s^{-n}e^s$ is an entire function. Estimate the the integral for the part of the contour in $\{ s : \operatorname{Re} s < C\}$ to see that $F(n) = 0$ for $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ with $n\leqslant 0$.

Comment: Actually, I've shown that $F(0) = 0$ and all other values $F(n)$ for $n \leq 0$ follow by induction. But thanks anyway!

Comment: I'll later post a full-detailed solution to my question. :)

Comment: You might find this article (https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.03933), and this post (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2274972/an-integral-formula-for-the-reciprocal-gamma-function) useful.